# Drop Down Box Not Fully Displayed (All Browsers)

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

[image: Screenshot of Drop Down]

This would be my issue I have a drop down that's not displaying fully. I'm not sure even where to start so here's the HTML surronding the drop down and I'll provide the CSS also.

HTML

```
<div id="add_item">
 <ul class="vert">
  <li>
   <ul class="horz">
    <li class="name">
     <select style="width: 195px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;" disabled="disabled">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="0">0</option>
     </select>

    </li>
    <li class="quantity">
     <select style="width: 50px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;" disabled="disabled">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="0">0</option>
     </select>
    </li>
   </ul>

  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

The reason the code has the drop down as being disabled is because it's dynamic, the surrounding HTML is the same except for having options to choose from and no longer being disabled.

CSS

```
div#byitem ul.horz li.name {
background:transparent none repeat scroll 0 0;
display:block;
font-size:11px;
font-weight:bold;
width:195px;
}

div#byitem ul.horz {
background:transparent none repeat scroll 0 0;
clear:left;
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
   
div#byitem ul.vert li {
background:transparent none repeat scroll 0 0;
height:14px;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

div#byitem ul.vert {
background:transparent none repeat scroll 0 0;
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
width:540px;
}

element.style {
margin-bottom:0;
margin-left:0;
margin-right:0;
margin-top:0;
padding-bottom:0;
padding-left:0;
padding-right:0;
padding-top:0;
width:195px;
}
#content form select {
margin:0 0 4px 4px;
z-index:1;
}
html, body, div, p, form, input, select, textarea, fieldset {
-x-system-font:none;
color:#333333;
font-family:Arial,Helvetica,Verdana,sans-serif;
font-size:11px;
font-size-adjust:none;
font-stretch:normal;
font-style:normal;
font-variant:normal;
font-weight:normal;
line-height:15px;
}
* {
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

## Edit

I've added the CSS for the divs that the drop downs are contained in. Also changing the line height doesn't make a difference. The only difference between the two drop downs (Item and Quantity) is the width. Changing the width on Item doesn't make a difference.

Took out the Add another item link as that was suspected to be a problem no change. Also I am doing my development in Firefox I just posted the screenshot from Safari.

Comment: I don't think there's enough info here to give a solution.  Using the code you supplied doesn't render anything like the problem stated.  Unless someone has seen this exactly before, we'd need to have at least enough code to replicate the problem in order to diagnose it.

Comment: I agree, it looks like the styles provided are not all of the styles in use on this page.  Do you have more code you can submit?

Comment: I still think there is code missing - the css references markup that isn't there

Comment: I simply changed a few div names and added 1 to surround it all.  I got it to work (sort of) that way.  My answer is below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are setting "line-height:15px;" on "select" elements. Remove that and see if it fixes the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If the styles on your elements are all identical for identical types (except for the width), it seems the only likely culprit is the surrounding elements in the page.  For example, what's the css/html for that "add another item" link below the problematic drop-down?

Comment: margin: 0px; padding: 10px 0pt 0pt 10px; text-align: left; display: none;

Comment: Whoops the display none is when the page initially loads then that goes off.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to check your page with the [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) plugin in Firefox. It can display and change the CSS style assigned to your element, and you will fix the issue in no time.

Comment: Try changing the CSS of surrounding elements.  In particular, try setting display: none on some of them to see if the artifact disappears in their absence.  Sorry if I'm beating a dead horse with this 'surrounding elements' thing. :)

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the DDL, but that something else on the page may be covering a part of it. In FireFox, try "Inspecting Element" on the whitespace that is at the bottom of the DDL.

Answer (score 0):

There might be no difference in the dropdowns; however, based on the code you provided, there is a difference in the `LI`s containing them.

You have a base style set for all list items, but you also have a specific style defined for `li.name`. I would focus on the `div#byitem ul.horz li.name` style. There's not enough code for me to reproduce it locally, but my guess would be that `display: block` is the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

Jeromy is correct, the difference is in the li containing the selects AND the surrounding elements considering you are floating the li's.

Try changing the height for the following style, see what your results are.

```
div#byitem ul.vert li {
    background:transparent none repeat scroll 0 0;
    height:17px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Hopefully that helps you track it down.

Answer (score 0):

Even if it doesn't end up solving the problem, I would strongly recommend pulling the `height:` declarations off both the `li` and the `select` elements.  The display sizes will be dependent on the font used by the browser.  Because you cannot control what fonts are installed on your users' computers, you cannot guarantee which font will be used by the browser.  Those heights will cause you problems sooner or later (and may be the cause of your current problem).